# Parsing large log file - Python

Tags: python, parsing, logfiles

I have a firewall log file which looks like this:

> "No.","Time","Source","Destination","Protocol","Info"
> "1","0.000000","172.16.113.168","172.16.112.50","TELNET","Telnet Data
> ..."  "2","0.000426","172.16.112.50","172.16.113.168","TELNET","Telnet
> Data ..."
> "3","0.019849","172.16.113.168","172.16.112.50","TCP","21582 > telnet
> [ACK] Seq=2Ack=2   Win=32120 Len=0"
> "4","0.530125","172.16.113.168","172.16.112.50","TELNET","Telnet Data
> ..."  "5","0.530634","172.16.112.50","172.16.113.168","TELNET","Telnet
> Data ..." "6","0.549962","172.16.113.168","172.16.112.50","TCP","21582
>
> > telnet [ACK] Seq=3 Ack=3 Win=32120 Len=0"

I want to be able to run the file by its name (I am using Linux) eg.

**log1.py logfile.csv** (name of the program followed by the name of the logfile)
and get the following output:

> **$ log1.py logfile.csv**
> Source IP      Destination IP   Protocol      Count
>
> ```
>         0.0.0.0     255.255.255.255      BOOTP         20
>     0.1.125.174         131.84.1.31        TCP          2
>     192.168.1.1         172.168.1.2        TCP        100 
>
>        (............lots more here .....................)
>
> Oracle_89:a5:9f       3com_9c:b2:54        ARP         14
>
>                                         Total:     649787
> ```

And another very useful feature I would like to have is when i run the program with a source IP address and destination IP address. I would like the output to look something similar to the following:

> **$ log1.py 172.16.112.50 logfile.csv**
>
> ```
>       Source IP      Destination IP   Protocol      Count
>
>   172.16.112.50      135.13.216.191        IMF          4
>                                           SMTP         53
>                                            TCP         43
>                                         TELNET         35
>         (............lots more here .....................)
>
>                      172.16.112.194       SMTP          7
>                                            TCP         42
>                                         TELNET       3745
>
>                                         Total:      38369
> ```

And finally, I would like to be able to specify both the source IP address and destination IP and adress and get the following output:

> **$ log1.py 172.16.112.50 202.77.162.213 packets.csv**
> Source IP      Destination IP   Protocol      Count
>
> ```
>   172.16.112.50      202.77.162.213       ICMP          1
>                                        Portmap          5
>                                            RSH          9
>                                        SADMIND          1
>                                            TCP         30
>                                         TELNET         41
>
>                                         Total:         87
> ```

I am a junior systems administrator and don't really have a lot of experience with programming (just HTML) I have started learning however, I have been stuck on this problem for the past 3 days here is what I have so far:

```
# Function for validating IP address is valid or not 
def ip_validation(ip_address):
    ip_regex= re.match('^[\d]{1,3}[.][\d]{1,3}[.][\d]{1,3}[.][\d]{1,3}$', ip_address)
    return ip_regex
def filereader(file_name):
    file_dump= open(file_name,'r')
    for eachline in file_dump:
        line_a= eachline.replace('\"','') # removes all quotes from the file
        line_b= line_a.split(',') # Delimate each fild based on ','             
        src_ip= line_b[2] # Source IP
        dst_ip= line_b[3] # Destination IP
        prot= line_b[4] # Protocol
        eachline= src_ip, dst_ip, prot      
        itlist.append(eachline) 
        itlist.sort()
        print itlist
```

Comment: If you familiarize youself with `pandas` library; this can be done in few lines of code. http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.15/tutorials.html

Answer (score 0):

parse logfile and create list of lists, where each sub-list containing (Source IP,Destination IP,Protocol,Count).

Now, all you have to apply [filter](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#filter) function on this outer list.
Reply if you need further clarification.

Comment: Thanks Palash I believe that I have created a list of list "itlist" contains (source ip, destination ip,protocol) how could i get count do I need to setup a control break to loop through all the items and count each? I know the idea in theory of whats needed I just cant get the program to do it. LOL.

Comment: Oh, I misunderstood. you do not have __count__ ready with you.
Only way **I can see** is to loop through sorted lists and counting on the fly.
I believe log file is static and not being updated while you are working on it.